# Merge of a detached head made lose changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I think I did a terrible mistake, but i hope you can help me.

I'm working with sourcetree, but I think after this mistake I'll learn how to use git bash.

Since two days I'm working on a detached head, and I didn't notice it, I made some commits and it went well, I then tried to merge my head in my dev branch (it is possible that I made it the other way). I resolved the sigle conflict and commited. my screen refreshed and my two last commits had disappeared and my changes too.

I hope there's a way to have those data back.

Best regards,

Mickael

Comment: Do you see your lost commits in the output of `git reflog`?

Comment: Yeah ! That's a good sign ! What should I do to pull them back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance to get back those commits. Git has a component named [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (reference log). It has a list of all commits you have *recently* made. So even if you delete a branch, for example, the commits from this branch will remain in the reflog, *for some time, 90 days by default*, and you can restore them.

Launch:

```
git reflog
```

and try to find your lost commit and simply create a new branch at that commit:

```
git branch my-lost-stuff <sha of the lost commit from the reflog>
```

Done, the commits are reachable again and you can continue with a `merge`, `rebase`, `cherry-pick`, `reset` etc.